# Grab information from a youtube playlist

Tags: javascript, .net, youtube

I've been wondering if I can use any method to grab information from a YouTube playlist, such like video IDs, how many videos are there, how long is the playlist, etc.
I've checked YouTube Data API already, but I was so confused.(I use .NET, but JavaScript also works to me)
Can anyone help?

Comment: What were you confused about?

Comment: I'm confused about how I call a YouTube data API method in my .NET code?

Comment: For .NET, did you look at [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet)?